# Different DNS answers per ip using bind DNS

Tags: dns, ip, bind

I need to configure bind DNS to respond different answers based on requesting IP.

as an example if user request example.com from 192.168.1.10 should get 1.1.1.1
and 2nd user request example.com from ip 192.168.1.11 should get 2.2.2.2

Is this possible with the bind DNS? if possible what is the performance impact if I configured this for more than 200 IP address. and if this not a good deployment what are the other ways to configure setup like this ?

Comment: Yes, it s possible in `bind`. Look at `view` and `acl` directives.

Comment: @heemayl thanks for the information ? performance vice is it a good setup ? could you please explain more ?

Comment: Your question is too broad now i am afraid. You should start reading and implementing...performance depends on the use case and this setup should not be too intense, of course YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring redundancy using DNS is not the  best strategy for several reasons.

As a poor man's stategy, you would much better defining multiple RRs than defining views.

However at 200 IP addresses, it seems either multiple RRs and views are not the best strategy. Both will give several technical problems.

For clustering, it would be better using clustering solutions, either paid or opensource. e.g cloudfront, fastly, varnish, relayd.

Using those solutions you will also got a lot of leg room to use multiple strategies to select the destination backend servers, and detecting which ones are down.